# Flow panel behaves like vertical panel in Google Script GUI Builder

Tags: google-apps-script

When I place two elements (buttons, etc.) side-by-side in a Flow Panel in the Google Apps Script GUI Builder, they are rearranged in a column.

In other words, the Flow Panel is behaving like a Vertical Panel, not a Flow Panel.

On a related note, the list of widgets in the GUI Builder includes a Vertical Panel, but not a Horizontal Panel.

Consequently, I can't place items side-by-side short of using absolute placement (which I imagine will not adjust properly for different window sizes).

Is this a bug? Is it being fixed? Is there a workaround?

(For reference, I'm working through the example in chapter 3 of James Ferreira's "Google Script" book.)

Comment: Can you include some sample code that illustrates the problem? If you believe this is a bug then it's better to post to the issue tracker than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to check is the width of your elements. I will admit that I almost never use the GUI Builder. Not that it doesn't work, it's just not how I write code.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce what you say, it works as expected.
As James was saying items width have to fit into the panel of course.[image: screen capture from the GUI builder]